# Get Tern type using its name

Tags: javascript, node.js, codemirror, tern

**Tl;dr version**:

Using `TernJS` for autocompletion purposes, I want to use a rule on a function, that taking a string as parameter, in order to return a type with the name same with the param given, for example:

```
foo("TypeA") returns +TypeA
foo("TypeB") returns +TypeB
```

In simple words, I am searching whether or not there is a notation in Tern that can give you a type using its name.

**Long version:**

Using `CodeMirror` in combination with `TernJS` set up in `NodeJS`, I am trying to simulate a custom factory behavior and provide similar capabilities in JavaScript in ES6:

```
//Module: Test.js
module.exports = (function() {

  var test = {};
  //....
  test.classA = class ClassA {
    constructor() {
      //....
    },
    foo() {}
    //....
  }

  test.factoryClass = class Factory {
    constructor() {
      //....
    }

    register(name, classData) { 
      //....
    }
    createInstance(name) {
      //....
    }
  }
  return test;
})();
```

Now, what I want to do is this:
If I have registered ClassA by doing:

```
var test = require("Test");

var factory = new test.factoryClass();
factory.register("ClassA", classA);
```

And I create a class instance of it:

```
var classAInst = factory.createInstance("ClassA");
```

I want in the editor to be able to get the methods of the `ClassA` instance.

```
classAInst.<AutoCompletion-KeyStroke> //This should give the completion list containing `foo`.
```

Now, I know that in order to get this, I need to have generated the TernJS Inference Engine rules in the .`json` definitions, so for ClassA and Factory I have something like:

```
{
  "Test" : {

    "ClassA": {
      "!type": "fn()"
      "prototype": {
         "foo": {
            "!type": "fn() -> string"
          }
      }
    }

    //....
    "Factory": {
      "prototype": {
        "register": {
          "!type": "fn(className: string, classDefinition: object)"
        },
        "createInstance": {
          "!type": "<This is what I need to specify properly>"
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

The problem is that I figured out how to form the rules by inspecting the `ecma6.json` file in the TernJS repo, as I was unable to find any documentation of the inference engine.

I tried doing something like this, attempting to tell the engine to index the type in a way, but it does not work (I suppose that `[]` is used for array definition only):

```
 "createInstance": {
   "!type": "fn(name: string) -> Test[!0]"
 }
```

So, any help on this would be appreciated. Any link or reference to the inference engine manual would be very helpful too, as I did not manage to find such information.